# Oracle 11G installer disappears in the middle of the install process

Tags: oracle11g

I am in the middle of the installation of *Oracle 11G* and the install wizard window just disappears as I click "next" button. Restrying the install process again did not solve the issue and [here is the last screen before the window vanishes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ej8L0.jpg).  Any idea on what may be going on here?

Comment: Which operating system is it? Did you follow the Installation Guide? Read prerequisites?

Comment: Which operating system is it? - Windows 7
Did you follow the Installation Guide - Yeah , I've done it . Step by step .The only error/problem i have it , is that my installer disappers when i hit next . 
Read prerequisites?  - Yeah , i have more than enough .

Comment: Did you try to log in as **administrator** and then run the installer? I mean literally *administrator*, not some user that has administrative privileges.

Comment: Did you try to log in as administrator and then run the installer? I mean literally administrator, not some user that has administrative privileges.
Yea. i have the same stuff happening .